# How to supress ununder warning for Lamda param in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Error: `Parameter 'buttonView' is never used, could be renamed to _`

Code:

```
checkImage.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            ......
        }
```

But I don't want to rename to "_" because I want it to be readbale and also I don't want to disable warning option from Android Studio as well, I just want to supress it, I tried with ununder but suggestion is still not going!

Comment: Have you added `@Suppress("unused")` before the above block of code?

Comment: @AnhPC03 Yes it is not working, do I have to run the project or compiler shd understand?

Comment: Try adding `@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")`